# Having trouble with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been attempting to get a simple rewrite done on a script for over two weeks now.

While it seems like it would be a simple task, any attempts to rewrite..
http://thebluecorsair.com/rank/index.php?character=Timbervvoif

to: http://thebluecorsair.com/rank/Timbervvoif result in the typical 404 response.

I've tried about twenty different answers, pages, as well as rewriting directly with PHP with no luck.

*Additionally, what would be the 301 redirect for this as well?*

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

Generated via http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite :

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^rank/([^/]*)$ /rank/index.php?character=$1 [L]

Comment: I tried that as well, still responds with a 404 response. Even removing everything else in the .htaccess, as well as any other conflicting commands still fails.

Comment: Still looking for assistance with this, could anybody help? Again, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I used the following code.

`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?character=$1 [QSA,NC]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ index.php?character=$1 [QSA,L]`